# Does the direction of Earth's axial tilt change over time? In relation to the sun? What about the 'pointy ends' of our ellipse?

Tags: astrophysics, astronomy

Does the direction we are tilted change in relation to the background stars?  And the points where our ellipse is pointiest? (most elongated?)  Does this change the timing of our aphelion and perihelion?  In other words, were they always one month after each solstice?

Also, are all of the planets' ellipses aligned?  So that the semi-major axis is the same?

Comment: The semi-major axes are not aligned.

Comment: For a detailed analysis, see [La2010: A new orbital solution for the long term motion of the Earth](https://arxiv.org/abs/1103.1084).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, yes and yes - these changes are called [axial precession](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axial_precession) and [apsidal precession](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apsidal_precession).